# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find during linking g++

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

This question has already been here so many times. But I didn't find the answer.

I have this `.cpp` file

```
#include <clickhouse/client.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace clickhouse;


int main(){
    /// Initialize client connection.
    Client client(ClientOptions().SetHost("localhost"));

    client.Select("SELECT l.a, l.b from table", [] (const Block& block)
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < block.GetRowCount(); ++i) {
                std::cout << block[0]->As<ColumnUInt64>()->At(i) << " "
                        << block[1]->As<ColumnString>()->At(i) << "\n";
            }
        }
    );
    return 0;
}
```

and I have instantiated SO library, like written [here](https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-cpp/issues/86#issuecomment-815104438).
after that i got the following structure of `/usr/local/lib directory`:

```
~/$ ls /usr/local/lib
>>libclickhouse-cpp-lib-static.a  libclickhouse-cpp-lib.so
```

in next step I trying execute compilation with `g++`

```
~/$ g++ run.cpp -std=c++17 -o result -llibclickhouse-cpp-lib -L/usr/local/lib
>>/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibclickhouse-cpp-lib
>>collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't know what hinders create links.

thank You for Your help!

Comment: Unrelated: `libclickhouse-cpp-lib-static.a` is an unfortunate name since the user would not only have to change from dynamic to `-static` linkage to get the static library, but would also need to change which library to use from `clickhouse-cpp-lib` to `clickhouse-cpp-lib-static`. Also, the `cpp-lib` part of the library name isn't very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ld`'s manual page describes the `-l` option as follows (irrelevant details omitted):

> -l namespec
>
> --library=namespec
>
> Add the archive or object file specified by namespec to the list of
> files to link. [...] ld will search a directory for a library called
> libnamespec.so

If you read this very carefully, you will reach the conclusion that `-llibclickhouse-cpp-lib` instructs `ld` to search for a library named `liblibclickhouse-cpp-lib.so` which, obviously, does not exist.

This should simply be `-lclickhouse-cpp-lib`.

Comment: Thnx! It's work. But I get error about incorrect path to library.
`$ ./result
./result: error while loading shared libraries: libclickhouse-cpp-lib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Depending on your compiler this either requires a `-R` or a `-Wl,-rpath` option, specifying the non-standard directory location where the library gets loaded at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the problem was solved when I change the Cmake version to 2.9

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33737705)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I./ -I./contrib -L./build/clickhouse/ -lclickhouse-cpp-lib-static -o demo demo.cpp ./build/clickhouse/libclickhouse-cpp-lib-static.a ./build/contrib/lz4/liblz4-lib.a ./build/contrib/cityhash/libcityhash-lib.a ./build/contrib/absl/libabsl-lib.a
```